# Getting a property from super() in Python which may change

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to build a framework and I am having problems with inheritance of properties between classes. I have a folder called framework with a **init**.py as follows:

```
from management import projects
from models import model

projects = projects()
model = model()
```

Then management looks like:

```
class projects(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._current = None

    @property
    def current(self):
        return self._current

    def set_current(self, name):
        """setting a project by name, then self._current = name"""
```

Finally models:

```
class model(projects):
    def __init__(self):
        super(model, self).__init__()

    @property
    def current(self):
        return super().current
```

Then when I try to use the framework from other script:

```
import framework as fw

fw.projects.set_current('foo')
fw.model.current
```

It returns None instead of 'foo'. I am pretty sure that the error is in the init file from framework where the instances are done before setting a project, I try some differents things but I don't have a clue. How can models class notice the changes in projects class?? Furthermore, I do not really want that model has the property current but I need its value for other methods (anyways I do not care if models has this property if it works as I expected). Thanks!!

EDIT:

For now I will store some metadata in the backend to access it from any class. But I am still wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Where did `simulation` come from?

Comment: change `super(model, self).__init__()` to `super(projects, self).__init__()`

Comment: Post edited, sorry!

Comment: With `super(projects, self).__init__()` I get the following error `AttributeError: 'model' object has no attribute '_current'`

Answer (score 1):

From my humble experience dealing intensively with Python in these last months, I would say it is absurd trying to access a children's property from the parent class because in this case, they are different instances.

```
projects = projects()
model = model()
```

Here you are creating two different instances and they do not share anything, so changes made in `project` won't be visible to `model`. I would recommend using composition over inheritance and inject a `Project` dependency onto `Model`.

Model class

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self, project):
        self.project = project

    def get_current(self):
        return self.project.get_current()
```

Project class

```
class Project:

    # in Python 3 there is no need to use the implicit-object inheritance
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = None

    def get_current(self):
        return self.current

    def set_current(self, value):
        self.current = value
```

Playing with them

```
from framework.Model import Model
from framework.Project import Project

project = Project()
model = Model(project)

project.set_current("Example")

print(model.get_current())  # Example
```

I hope this helps.

Tomás.

Comment: Thanks Tomás! I was thinking about something like this solution. Which I'll use if I do not achieve the expected behavour of `fw.projecs` and `fw.model` separately. I am now trying with observers.